# Vendor WMS parameters not sent in GetMap requests via QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms

When adding WMS layers through Python plugin/script I run into issue with QGIS stripping of vendor parameters. I found following issue that was closed (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12255). Proposed solution doesn't with checking settings in GUI "Ignore GetMap/GetTile URI reported in capabilities" is not good for my case, as I am doing it from Python script.

Is there way to activate this setting from Python script. Or is there any other work around?

Also the solution in this post ([Non-standard WMS parameters not sent in GetMap requests via QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120348/non-standard-wms-parameters-not-sent-in-getmap-requests-via-qgis)) is not getting me anywhere, because WMS has to get & not encoded to parse it correctly.

Comment: Can you share the code in the question?